# Is Box.add() thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, user-interface, thread-safety

is

```
function(Component C){ Box.add(C);validate();}
```

Thread-safe or does it need to be called in an EventsDispatcherThread?

if they need to be called in the Events Dispatcher Thread, do both Box.add as well as validate() need to be inside the EDT or only box.add is?

Comment: Don't use validate(). Instead you should use `revalidate()` when using Swing. Also, follow Java naming conventions. Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should run your code in the event dispatch thread.

As you can read in Oracle documentation:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html

You can use Swing classes outside EDT only if they are marked as thread safe in the documentation.

Comment: should Box.add as well as validate (or revalidate as suggested) be in an events dispatcher thread? or only box.add?